# Toggling content div on one-page site with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, fadein, fadeout

I'm building a portfolio section on a website that will be limited to 4 items. Each item has an image and description that are visible, and a details section that's hidden by default.

The idea is to have the details section fade in when the link for that item is clicked. I have a working fiddle that I put together, but if there's already a details section visible and you click another link, there's a bit of chunky overlap taking place.

This is a snippet of what I'm using to control each detail section:

You can see the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ERP7L/6/

```
$("a#project-1-link").click(function(){
  $("div#project-2-details, div#project-3-details, div#project-4-details").fadeOut("",function(){
      $("div#project-1-details").fadeIn(""); 
  });  
});
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this that will clean up this lag? I tried using a delay on the fadeIn, but it didn't work either.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a callback on the `.fadeOut()`, This is the syntax:

```
$(divToHide).fadeOut(400, function() {
    $(divToShow).fadeIn();
});
```

This only works (smoothly) if the `fadeOut()` function is only called once--on the visible element.  So the best thing would be to find the visible div, and target just that one, instead of targeting all the `-details` divs:

```
var visibleDiv = $('.nav ~ div').filter(function() { return $(this).is(':visible'); });
```

Then the callback would look like so:

```
$(visibleDiv).stop().fadeOut(400, function() {
    $(divToShow).fadeIn();
});
```

I'd also add `.stop()` to prevent multiple fadings in and out from piling up.

Also, worthy of noting, this is doable without creating different functions for each link.  Just use something like:

```
$('.nav a').click(function(event) {
    var currentElement = $(event.currentTarget);
    var divToShow = $(currentElement).attr('id').replace('link', 'details');
    ....
});
```

To get the div you need to show from any link you click.  So, all together the jQuery looks like:

```
$('.nav a').click(function(event) {
    var currentElement = $(event.currentTarget);
    var divToShow = $(currentElement).attr('id').replace('link', 'details');

    var visibleDiv = $('.nav ~ div').filter(function() { return $(this).is(':visible'); });
    if (visibleDiv.length) // if there is a div already visible, fade it out then fade in the target div
    {
        $(visibleDiv).stop().fadeOut(400, function() {
            $('#' + divToShow).fadeIn();
        });
    }
    else $('#' + divToShow).fadeIn(); // fade it in.
});
```

I also added that `if` statement so there's no delay in fading in the first div.

[**JSFiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ERP7L/8/).  Hope this helps!

Comment: This works well! The only thing that's not working is my scroll-to-anchor (which is a separate script I'm using throughout the rest of my site, taken from here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/). Each project-link has an href="project-1-details" attribute that should be causing the scroll-to-anchor function. If project-1-details is already visible, and I click the project-1-link, this scroll-to-anchor script works well. But it won't scroll on the first click. How would I go about adding that additional functionality?

Comment: @EricWood I couldn't say without seeing the code.  Off the top of my head, maybe triggering a second click on the `project-link` `a` tag after you've faded in its target. As in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ERP7L/12/

Comment: You can see this issue in play here: http://jsfiddle.net/ERP7L/14/ - The second time you click the link, you get the action I'm looking for. I also added the same script to the close button, so it slides you back up to the nav section and that one seems to be working completely fine. I've also targeted the #project-1-details, etc. divs specifically in the js so the other divs on the page aren't affected. I did find one way to add that function in (see here: http://jsfiddle.net/ERP7L/15/) but it's a little chunky at times, and doesn't slide until the div has already faded in.

Comment: I believe it doesn't slide immediately because the slide function registers that there is already an animation happening on `'html, body'` (that's the div fading in) so it waits for it to finish before animating the `scrollTop` downward.  There's a workaround, potentially messy, if you add `.stop()` or `.finish()` in the scrolling function: `$('html,body').finish().animate({ ... }, 750);` Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bowheart/ERP7L/16/

Answer (score 0):

One trick is to use `position: absolute` so that the `DIV` elements (content) occupy the same space and crossfade nicely. I also removed a lot of duplicate code by using `className` instead of `id`.

Fixed JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/os8zmhgc/

Runnable snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("A", ".nav").click(function() {
    var targetId = $(this).data("target");
    var $targetDiv = $("#project-" + targetId + "-details");
    $(".project-details").fadeOut();
    $targetDiv.fadeIn();
  });
  $("a.close").click(function() {
    $(".project-details").fadeOut();
  });
});
```

```css
div.nav {
  margin: 20px 0;
}
.project-details {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 40px;
}
a.close {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: -30px;
  left: -40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
  <a href="#" id="project-1-link" data-target="1">One</a>
  <a href="#" id="project-2-link" data-target="2">Two</a>
  <a href="#" id="project-3-link" data-target="3">Three</a>
  <a href="#" id="project-4-link" data-target="4">Four</a>
</div>
  <div id="project-1-details" class="project-details">
    <a class="close">x</a>
    <strong>One.</strong> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</div>
  <div id="project-2-details" class="project-details">
    <a class="close">x</a>
    <strong>Two.</strong> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</div>
  <div id="project-3-details" class="project-details">
    <a class="close">x</a>
    <strong>Three.</strong> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</div>
  <div id="project-4-details" class="project-details">
    <a class="close">x</a>
    <strong>Four.</strong> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

hows this:

```js
$('body').on('click', '#nav > a', function(){
  var detail = $('#nav-details > div:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')');
  detail.siblings().fadeOut().promise().done(function(){
    detail.fadeIn();
  });
});
$('body').on('click', '#nav-details .close', function(){
  $(this).parent().fadeOut();
});
```

```css
#nav{
    margin:20px 0;
}
#nav-details > div{
    display:none;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    padding:40px;
    position: relative;
}
span.close{
    cursor:pointer;
    background:white;
    color:black;
    padding:10px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav">
  <a href="#">One</a>
  <a href="#">Two</a>
  <a href="#">Three</a>
  <a href="#">Four</a>
</div>
<div id="nav-details">
  <div>
    <span class="close">x</span>
    <strong>One.</strong> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="close">x</span>
    <strong>Two.</strong> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="close">x</span>
    <strong>Three.</strong> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="close">x</span>
    <strong>Four.</strong> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I think some jealous soul just went through and down-voted everything.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first. Try to use classes if you want to do the same action on every element. (With the same action I mean: open and close)

So, you can still use the ID for a very specific reason and the classes for a generic one.

I've tried to do it more simple without many modifications to the html part. But I recommend to you to put the links and the details into containers.

Here's a solution, I know it seems complex... Maybe with a fadeToggle would be better. But it's neccessary to modify the DOM.

Here's your HTML (With classes and data- attributes) :

```
<div class="nav">
<a href="#" id="project-1-link" class="project" data-id="1">
    One     
</a>


<a href="#" id="project-2-link"  class="project" data-id="2">
    Two     
</a>


<a href="#" id="project-3-link"  class="project" data-id="3">
    Three  
</a>

<a href="#" id="project-4-link"  class="project" data-id="4">
    Four  
</a>




<div id="project-1-details" class="details">
    <a class="close">x</a>
    <strong>One.</strong> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
</div>

<div id="project-2-details"  class="details">
    <a class="close">x</a>
    <strong>Two.</strong> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
</div>

<div id="project-3-details"  class="details">
    <a class="close">x</a>
    <strong>Three.</strong> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
</div>


<div id="project-4-details"  class="details">
    <a class="close">x</a>
    <strong>Four.</strong> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
</div>
```

The data-id is to know that number i'm calling, we're going to use it on the script, so you don't have to write one line of code for each element.

here's the script:

```
$(function(){
    $(".project").on("click", function(){

     // HERE WE TAKE THE NUMBER OF THE ID FROM THE CLICKED OBJECT

     var dataid = $(this).attr("data-id");

     // THEN WE FADE OUT EVERYTHING IS VISIBLE
     $(".details").fadeOut();

     //HERE, WE'LL TAKE THE ONE WE'RE GONNA FADE IN
     setTimeout(function(){
        $("#project-"+dataid+"-details").fadeIn();
     },400)
  });
})
```

And Here's the jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mpcguc4k/

Sorry for the long answer.